# PHP Fatal Error Call to Undefined Method...that I'm 99% sure is defined

Tags: php, mysql, methods, undefined

#### session.php

```
include("database.php");

function addPOTW($subweek, $subtitle, $subcaption, $subsubmittedby)
{
    global $database, $form;
    /* Errors exist, have user correct them */
    if ($form->num_errors > 0) {
        return 1; // Errors with form
    }
    /* No errors, add the new POTW to the database */
    else {
        if ($database->addNewPOTW($subweek, $subtitle, $subcaption, $subsubmittedby, $subfile)) {
            return 0; //Event signup added succesfully
        } else {
            return 2; //Event signup attempt failed
        }
    }
}
```

This is my function, "addPOTW", located in the file session.php (with useless parts redacted). For some reason, I keep getting the error message: **"Fatal error: Call to undefined method MySQLDB::addNewPOTW()"** even though it's defined right here:

#### database.php

```
class MYSQLDB {
    function addNewPOTW($date, $title, $caption, $submitter, $filepath)
        {
            $q = "INSERT INTO `" . TBL_POTW . "` VALUES ('','$date','$title','$caption','$submitter','$filepath')";
            return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
        }
}
```

I have other functions in session.php accessing functions in database.php using the $database variable in the *exact same way*, and they work perfectly fine. Any ideas why only this one function is being reported as undefined??

Comment: Are you sure the version of `database.php` being used in the application is the same one you're looking at?

Comment: Also try `var_dump($database)` right before you call the method.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are referring to `$this`, you would need to instantiate an object from that class and then call the method.

Something like this should get it working...

```
$database = new MYSQLDB;
```

Make sure you have it in scope before your `addPOTW()` function.

Comment: Can't use `static` as it makes use of `$this`

Comment: @Phil: Thanks, didn't notice that. Fixed.

Comment: I believe the global (eww) `$database` is *meant to be* an instance of `MYSQLDB`. FYI, unless indicated by `public`, `protected` or `private` keyword, class methods (functions) are implicitly `public`

Comment: @Phil: Yeah, that's what I assumed. Everything public except noted otherwise is a relic from PHP4's *OO* implementation I believe.